# Asp.net MVC3 with LINQ to SQL on multiple identical tables

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3, scaffolding

I successfully retrieved data from an already populated table of a live database using mvc3 and linq 2 SQL. The table is defined in the DataClasses1.dbml.

Now I have to retrieve data from other tables with the same identical structure of DataClasses1 but from different databases on the same SQL Server( DB1.Customers DB2.Customers ecc), and display them grouped by database name.

1) How can I do that without creating N DataClassesN.dbml ? I guess since it's the same table structure I can avoid doing it.

2) (Optional): How can I automatically retrieve data also from tables of new created databases?

3) (Not relevant): How can I define a strongly type view? Seems I can do it using EF but I cannot do it using LINQ 2 SQL.

- I already thought of creating a view on the database with all the customers tables, but it seems it's a too heavy view!
- I have a query that returns all the database names (Select name from master..syttables), is it useful?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should reconsider your database design. If this data is being used by a single application, is consistently structured, and you want to work with it as a single data type then it should all exist in *one* table in *one* database. Add a column to determine which 'subset' it belongs to, if necessary.

Comment: @Kirk Broadhurst - There are lots of reasons why one wouldn't want to do that.  For instance, I developed an app where there were multiple customers, and each customer needed to be able to "take their data with them" when they leave, so this necessitating making each customer use their own database.  What's best from a programmers perspective isn't always whats best from a business one.

Comment: @Mystere Man - "Taking their own data" isn't a sufficient requirement to giving them their own database, in my mind. Having 200 customers necessitating 200 databases? That's just unmaintainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just pass a different connection string to the data context when you create it.  If the databases are truly identical, including all the foreign key relationships, then just do something like:

```
var dc = new DataClasses1(db1connectionstring);
// Do your display of database 1 data
var dc2 = new DataClasses1(db2connectionstring);
// Do your display of database 2 data
```

I have no idea what you mean by #2.  Data doesn't retrieve itself.

Comment: he wants to group and join and group tables across the databases. is it possible even if we create two datacontext objects with different connection strings

Comment: @Muhammad Adeel Zahid - I have read and reread his question, and I don't see where he is asking to join or group tables across databases.  He's just asking about using the same data classes for different databases with the same structure.  When he says "group by database name" he just means he wants to list the database name, then display the data from that database, followed by listing another database name and the data from THAT database.

Comment: i think @Attila is in much better position to speak about this than me

Comment: re #2, I'd assume he's going to have an unknown collection of databases in his server, and wants his data access layer to retrieve the data from each database dynamically.

Comment: Exactly Kirk Broadhurst, any idea of how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't obviously join results from 2 databases in SQL so you'd probably have to use 2 queries (one to each database) with one of them selecting into a new Entity of the other database and then join the results in memory using LINQ afterwards. So one query returns DB1.EntityName and the other returns DB2.EntityName but with a select mapping this to new DB1.EntityName entities and then join the two. It's not a pretty solution but is the best I can think of off the top of my head.

If you just want each database to have a set of results each then obvioulsy you can just return 2 result sets. Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Actually, yes.  You can do cross-database queries in SQL, joining tables or results from each database into a single query.  Doing it in EF or L2S is a different matter though.

Comment: I more meant from an EF standpoint. Thanks for clarifying though. From EF this would require 2 context connections and have to merge results afterwards.